# How to resize Xcode simulator/ skView size

Tags: ios, xcode, skscene, skview

I've tried to resize my SKView for my app using multiple different methods given to me from multiple people. Here is what I am trying to get rid of:

[image: Screenshot of X]

Do you see the scroll bar on the right? When I scrolled up that is where the default "hello world" text was, how do I get rid of that?

The view you can see is only about 40% of what the simulator is loading.

Comment: @crashoverride here is a picture of what i am talking about, i can't add pictures in comments

Comment: Open your simulator and select it then you need to select scale % option which is under Window top menu option of your mac..

Comment: You can refer below screen shot image url to go scale option in your mac
http://postimg.org/image/e04p7r3xd/